# Best practice to convert a local script into a (Catalyst) web app

Tags: perl, frameworks, catalyst

I've developed a bioinformatics tool in Perl which runs fine locally. Basically it reads in a text file and some user-defined parameters from CLI. It calculates some values and generates bar graphs. The final report is an HTML file.

To share this functionality with others, I'd like to convert it into a web app. Instead of working with output files, the data will be stored in a MySQL database.
I tinkered with the Catalyst framework to manage things like user registration/login, input forms and database interaction.

Now what is the best pratice to get the actual business logic (approx. 1,000 lines of code) into the web app? Putting the code in a Catalyst model? Or calling the script out of Catalyst? How would you do it?

Comment: This is a bit broad for SO, but in general you would put it in a model. Make sure it's all functions, so you can turn them into methods. The output would not be a HTML page any more, but rather a bunch of data that goes into the Stash, and from there would be rendered using a View (probably TT). If you are also creating graphs, those a probably images. You could inline those directly into the page, or provide a Controller that makes them on the fly based on some database id or other arguments. Both of those approaches are preferable over creating files on disk with every request.

Comment: Are you sure you want a MySQL, or is SQLite enough for you? Depending on your hosting environment, SQLite might be cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.So I would convert the actual script into a library of  functions and 'use' them in the Model right? I'm thinking about replacing static graphs with SVG using morris.js or so. That should work with your suggestion to create them on the fly. Regarding the database: I'm quite familiar with MySQL and like MySQL Workbench and phpmyadmin. Do you think SQlite is worth giving it a try?

Comment: You can do that, and use the model as glue. Or you can just move all of it into the model directly.